# Php files fail to load in IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I have a little bit of problem. All my php files fail to load in Internet Explorer. When I'm giving it a run from Notepad++, IE opens shortly(0.1s), a dowloading box, then redirects the file to Chrome. HTML files are loading fine. Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: you'd need to have xampp installed for setting up an local server to run your php scripts.
http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: You cannot directly run a php file by opening it in browser unlike html files. PHP is a server-side scripting language. It needs to be run on server.

Comment: you can not run Php file directly in a browser , as PHP is a server side scripting language

Comment: that makes no sense, since php is a server side language, all the browser is getting are html retuns

Comment: Pretty legitimate questions don't see why it needed any downvotes. Only easy if you know how.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. I understood the problem. Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a server running to serve PHP files.

If you are on a windows machine try installing http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

If you are on a Mac try [Mamp](http://www.mamp.info/en/)

Any of the above installations will install Apache, MySQL and PHP which is all that you need to run common PHP application. These are essentially one-click installs so this should set you up very quickly.